# Confusion using with double value, when groovy decides to make value in double vs BigDecimal?

Tags: groovy, double, bigdecimal

I'm little bit confused using `double` value.

When I used as below :-

```
double foo = 20.46455
assert 20 == foo.round()
assert 20.46 == foo.round(2)
```

It's working fine. but when I used something like as :-

```
def foo = 20.46455
assert 20 == foo.round()
```

it throws :-

> java.lang.NullPointerException

and

```
def foo = 20.46455
assert 20.46 == foo.round(2)
```

it throws :-

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.math.BigDecimal.round() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [2]
>   Possible solutions: round(java.math.MathContext), find(), pow(int), power(java.lang.Integer), find(groovy.lang.Closure), and(java.lang.Number)

It means by default in `groovy`, value preserve in `BigDecimal` and `BigDecimal.round()` expect [`java.math.MathContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html) as input.

But My confusion start when I'm using [`Math.round()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)) which except `double` as input then **why below statement is getting passed while groovy preserve by default in `BigDecimal`**?

```
def foo = 20.46455
assert 20 == Math.round(foo)
```

And why I have to use `.toDouble()` to pass my test case while `foo` has value in `double` format as below?

```
def foo = 20.46455
assert 20 == foo.toDouble().round()
assert 20.46 == foo.toDouble().round(2)
```

**Note** :- I don't want to know how to `round` a double value, I just want to know why `groovy` behaves differently in each case??

Comment: @yash I don't want to round number I'm just want to know why `groovy` behaves differently in each case. Thanks..:)

Comment: @NathanHughes Actually I know how to round `BigDecimal` or `Double`..And yes, you are right my question is `when groovy decides to make something a double vs BigDecimal?`

Comment: I have also update the title of the question, Thanks..:)

Comment: dont forget to add missing datatype instead of letting groovy assume ! worked for me!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Groovy automatically and implicitly uses BigDecimal for any floating-point numbers unless you define a type or you add a suffix for the number (like D).

**Examples:**

```
def foo = 20.46455
println foo.getClass()
```

**Output:**

> class java.math.BigDecimal

```
double foo = 20.45645
println foo.getClass()
```

**Output:**

> class java.lang.Double

```
def foo = 20.45645d
println foo.getClass()
```

**Output:**

> class java.lang.Double

**Type conversions:**

Groovy also has certain automatic type conversions and this is the reason why even though `Math.round()` only accepts `double` and `float` primitives as parameters, the code is not failing when you pass a BigDecimal. To prove this, you could implement your own `round` function and check what happens with the type conversions:

**Examples:**

```
def round(double foo) {
   println foo.getClass()
   return foo.round()
}

def foo = 20.46455
println foo.getClass()
assert 20 == round(foo)
```

**Output:**

> class java.math.BigDecimal
>
> class java.lang.Double

Some more valid examples of implicit conversions:

```
def round(float foo) {
   println foo.getClass()
   return foo.round()
}

def foo = 20.46455
println foo.getClass()
assert 20 == round(foo)
```

**Output:**

> class java.math.BigDecimal
>
> class java.lang.Float

```
def round(float foo) {
   println foo.getClass()
   return foo.round()
}

def foo = 20
println foo.getClass()
assert 20 == round(foo)
```

**Output:**

> class java.lang.Integer
>
> class java.lang.Float

```
def round(double foo) {
   println foo.getClass()
   return foo.round()
}

def foo = 20
println foo.getClass()
assert 20 == round(foo)
```

**Output:**

> class java.lang.Integer
>
> class java.lang.Double

```
def round(BigDecimal foo) {   
   println foo.getClass()
   return foo
}

double foo = 20.0
println foo.getClass()
assert 20 == round(foo)
```

​
**Output:**

> class java.lang.Double
>
> class java.lang.BigDecimal

As a rule of thumb, if the number is floating point based (`double`, `float`, `BigDecimal`) there will be an implicit type conversion between each other, and the code will throw an exception when trying to convert to non-floating point numbers (like `int` or `long`). If a number is not a floating point type (`int`, `long`), it can be converted between non-floating and floating point types, as floating point numbers also include non-floating points as a subset (e.g. 1 can be represented with 1.0). This makes sense, as you can't pass the floating point information from a float to an int (20.5 can't be represented with an `int` variable), but in most cases you can do the opposite, with the occasional exception of overflows for big values (e.g a really big `long` number into a `float` variable).

Comment: Then why it [`def foo = 20.46455;assert 20 == Math.round(foo)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)) get passed??

Comment: `def foo = 20.46455` lets Groovy decide what type this variable has using type inference, and it chooses BigDecimal. `double foo = 20.46455` forces the variable to be a `double` type. You could alternatively use a suffix to force the `double` declaration like this `def foo = 20.46455D`

Comment: But it get passed without forcing to `double`, that's why I'm confused, I'm using only `double foo = 20.46455` and groovy automatically takes it as `double` when use it as `assert 20 == Math.round(foo)` but when I used it as `foo.round()` groovy takes it as `BigDecimal` and it throws exception...

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean now. Groovy also has automatic type conversions. Let me extend my answer to include this.

Comment: +1 Yes, it makes little bit sense. But how groovy decides when it will use as `double` and when `BigDecimal`??? is this decided on the basis of method refrence??

Comment: If the object itself is a BigDecimal `def foo = 20.46455`, and you try to call a method which is not implemented for a BigDecimal (like `round()`) it will throw an exception. But if you are passing it as a parameter, Groovy will try to accomodate the type (like `BigDecimal` passed to a method expecting a `double` or a `float` parameter), but it will still throw an exception if the conversion is not possible. I will extend a bit more my answer to show more implicit conversions.

Comment: Thanks for your input, really appreciate..:)

Comment: Happy I could help! If this solves all your questions could set it as the right answer? Thanks!